# How to run a script after mysql container initialization?

Tags: mysql, docker, containers

So, I want that a script run just after the MySQL Docker container started (and had gone through the entrypoint defined in the `mysql` image), I know about the existence of `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, but there is a problem with this approach that I don't know how to fix: the script is executed under `mysql` user, not `root`, and I need `root` access.

I tried creating a custom entrypoint that would source the `docker-entrypoint.sh`, but it did not work:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo aaaa
source /.../docker-entrypoint.sh
_main "$@"
echo bbbb
```

This did not work, MySQL was not initialized after (the echos worked though).

So, what should I do to run a script as `root` after the initialization of the database?

Comment: What does the script actually need to do?  (Why do you need to be root?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
├── Dockerfile
└── entrypoint.sh
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM mysql:latest

COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

`entrypoint.sh` (This is the customised entrypoint. It runs the entrypoint from the base image then waits for the MySQL server to become available. Once it's available it confirms that the current user is `root` and then it's ready to do whatever you require.)

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld >/dev/null 2>&1  &
PID="$!"

while ! mysqladmin ping -h"localhost" --silent; do
    echo " Wait for MySQL to be ready..."
    sleep 1
done

echo " MySQL is ready."
echo " Current user: $(whoami)"

# Do other things here...

wait "$PID"
```

[image]